# Ruby has no "String#substrings_between(start, end)", what should I use?

Tags: ruby, substring

I have a very complex string, such as:

```
<p>aaa <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>
<p>bbb <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>
<p>ccc <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>
....
```

Now I want to get the `aaa`,`bbb`,`ccc` parts. I don't want to use regular expression here, because it's too complicated to turn the `<font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>` part to a regex.

I hope there is a method (say `substrings_between`), I can use it like this:

```
substrings = text.substrings_between('<p>', ' <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>');
substrings # -> [aaa, bbb, ccc]
```

Is there such a method? Or what's the best way to do?

Comment: You're using the `font` tag which should be dead and buried long time ago, using inline styles rather than CSS classes, and misspelling the `style` attributes, all in the same line?

Comment: What I want to do is get some message from a web page. And that's the content of that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should parse HTML using a proper parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

That said, if you know for certain that what you need is located between two hard-coded strings, you could use *scan* and a regular expression:

```
string = '<p>aaa <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>
          <p>bbb <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>
          <p>ccc <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>'

before = Regexp.escape '<p>'
after  = Regexp.escape ' <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>'

substrings = string.scan(/#{before}(.*?)#{after}/).flatten
 => ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

Comment: D'oh! I forget about `Regexp#escape`!

Answer (score 2):

The following method will do the job

```
def substring_between(target, match1, match2)
  start_match1 = target.index(match1)
  if start_match1 && start_match2 = target.index(match2, start_match1 + match1.length)
    start_idx = start_match1 + match1.length
    target[start_idx, start_match2 - start_idx]
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

If you want to create this as an instance method on the string class then this should work for you

```
class String
  def substring_between(sub1, sub2)
    match1 = self.index(sub1)
    if match1 && match2 = self.index(sub2, match1 + sub1.length)
      idx = match1 + sub1.length
      self[idx, match2 - idx]
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Both implementations return nil if the start or end tags don't exist or are in the wrong order. The following test script and results show it working

```
strings = [
'No tags at all',
'<font End tag before start tag <p>',
'<p>End tag at end <font',
'No start tag <font',
'<p>No end tag',
'<p>aaa <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>',
'    <p>bbb <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>',
'<p>ccc     cccc<font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p>'
]

strings.each do |s|
  puts "Method Test = #{s} Result: |#{substring_between(s, '<p>', '<font')}|"
  puts "String Test = #{s} Result: |#{s.substring_between('<p>', '<font')}|"
end
```

```
Method Test = No tags at all Result: ||
String Test = No tags at all Result: ||
Method Test = <font End tag before start tag <p> Result: ||
String Test = <font End tag before start tag <p> Result: ||
Method Test = <p>End tag at end <font Result: |End tag at end |
String Test = <p>End tag at end <font Result: |End tag at end |
Method Test = No start tag <font Result: ||
String Test = No start tag <font Result: ||
Method Test = <p>No end tag Result: ||
String Test = <p>No end tag Result: ||
Method Test = <p>aaa <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p> Result: |aaa |
String Test = <p>aaa <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p> Result: |aaa |
Method Test =     <p>bbb <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p> Result: |bbb |
String Test =     <p>bbb <font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p> Result: |bbb |
Method Test = <p>ccc     cccc<font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p> Result: |ccc     cccc|
String Test = <p>ccc     cccc<font style="color:red">ABCD@@@EFG^&*))*T*^[][][]</p> Result: |ccc     cccc|
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, you gave me useful skills. Although I want here is "substring**s**_between", but thank you all the same

Answer (score 1):

Use [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

```
string = '<span id="span_is"><br><br><u><i>Hi</i></u></span>'
strip_tags(string)  # Will Return  'Hi'
```

Comment: thanks. My task is much harder than this, so what I want is not just strip tags, but get the substrings between some keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to build the function yourself. Something like:

```
def substrings_between str, opening, ending
  i_opening = str.index opening
  i_ending = str.index ending
  res = []
  while i_opening && i_ending
    res << str[i_opening+opening.length .. i_ending]
    str = str[i_ending+ending.length .. -1]
    i_opening = str.index opening
    i_ending = str.index ending
  end
  res
end
```

(This code isn't too much Ruby-like, but it works well).

Comment: thanks. there is a minor mistake: `i_ending = str.index ending` should be `str.index ending, i_opening+opening.length`

Comment: @Freewind, what do you mean? The code as it is seems to work for me, and changing i_ending = str.index ending for str.index ending, i_opening+opening.length gives an error (and I don't understand what you intend).

Comment: please try `substrings_between "abcba", "b", "a"`, the result is `["", "cba"]`. I think the correct result should be `["cb"]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you're looking for is probably too specific to be in the Ruby distribution.

We can probably assemble it using

```
String#index(string, offset)
```

Then we could write something like this (extending String):

```
class String
  def delimited_strings(start_delim, end_delim)
    strings = []
    starts_at = index(start_delim) 
    return strings unless starts_at
    ends_at = index(end_delim, starts_at + start_delim.size)
    while starts_at && ends_at do
      strings << self[starts_at+start_delim.size...ends_at]
      starts_at = index(start_delim, starts_at + end_delim.size)
      ends_at = index(end_delim, starts_at + start_delim.size) if starts_at
    end
    strings
  end
end

s = "<p>aaa<font>xxx</font></p><p>bbb<font>xxx</font></p><p>ccc<font>xxx</font></p>"
s.delimited_strings("<p>", "<font") #=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a minor mistake? `ends_at = index(end_delim, starts_at+1` => `ends_at = index(end_delim, starts_at + start_delim.length`? I think `+1` is not enough, if you consider `start_delin=abc, end_delim=bc`

Comment: @Freewind - eek, you're right. Inadequate test conditions. Code changed to (hopefully) be more resilient...